# how to print the exact word from a file by using grep?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, grep

I have this file call helloworld.txt:

> starthelloworld_some_text.jpgend 
>   starthelloworld_different_text.jpgend 
>   starthelloworld_another_different_one.jpgend

and I would like Grep to display only like this:

> helloworld_some_text.jpg 
>   helloworld_different_text.jpg 
>   helloworld_another_different_text.jpg

I a newbie and really need help from you guys. Please show me some ways, I really appreciate for your time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep -o "hello.*\.jpg" helloworld.txt`